# Is there any reason for an application to be installed in AppData on Win7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, compatibility, appdata

I installed the [Zoom Client for Meetings](https://zoom.us/download#client_4meeting) on a Win7 box.

This software is a popular application used by many people (in other words, it's not just some shady random piece of software).

What surprised me is that the application installed itself in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Zoom\`.

I've never seen an application install itself in `AppData` before.  (They always use `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)`.)

Is this an error by the development team, or does it sometimes make sense to install an application into `AppData`?

(As a side-question, Windows' application compatibility assistant popped up and asked if the application was installed correctly.  Since the application appeared to work, I did not try an immediate reinstall via the compatibility assistant.  What would have happened if I did?)

Comment: It's not uncommon. When you have software that is just being installed for a specific user instead of system-wide, it will usually go in that folder. Even Chrome installs itself there when you choose "just for this user."

Comment: Chrome for the longest time installed to AppData.

Comment: Each AppData folder is allocated only for that current user. So installing in that folder will not affect other users in that machine.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is perfectly normal and expected behavior.

Applications that install for only one user do this. This usually includes programs that give you an option to install for “this user only” or “all users” of this computer. The former is installed under AppData - for one specific user.

This is also a good indication that the application does NOT require elevated permissions to run. Applications do not have write permissions in the `Program Files` folders unless you click to Allow the program to “make changes to your computer,” during installation.

For these reasons, it is perfectly normal for an application like this to install under AppData. It is designed for one specific user, and does not require elevated permissions to function.

Another interesting fact is that the application will only show up under your user account when viewing the “Programs & Features” listing. As a systems admin, you may notice that “non-admin” users have certain applications installed and showing up in the “Programs & Features” list. You may immediately question how that user was able to install software on the computer. But, the reasons above are why. It did not require admin permissions. If the admin then logs in, they will NOT see the application in their programs listing. The application has to also be uninstalled by the same user who installed it. This can be a source of confusion as some applications can be installed simultaneously for one user account and system-wide for all user accounts.

Comment: Thank you for the details.  You wrote: *Applications that install for only one user do this. This usually includes programs that give you an option to install for “this user only” or “all users” of this computer.*  I guess it would have been nice if the installer presented such an option, but it didn't.  At least I now know *why* it got installed there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a normal practice.

This is mostly for administrative reasons and is known as [Install Context](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/installation-context)

Install context allows admins to specify if the application is to be installed in user context or system context. Installing application in system context allows an administrator to make the application available for all the users in a computer. Similarly, installing application in user context allows an application to be made available for only one user.

Re-installing the application wouldn't have changed this behavior.

[Another good read](https://shieldmaster.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/understanding-per-user-or-per-machine-context-for-application-setup-packages/)

Answer (score 1):

I just found this thread after using ninite to 'update' zoom (which is IMHO a pain to upgrade from within the app).

Ninite installed zoom in program files (x86) folder.  AND removed the files from the appdata zoom folder (so it knew there was already an install on the machine).

The original installs of zoom don't ask if you want it for just you or all users of the computer.